# Check if a string ends in is valid or not in java using regex

Tags: java, regex

I have the following requirement where in I need to do few things only if the given string ends in "Y" or "Years" or "YEARS".

I tried doing it using regex like this.

```
String text=1.5Y;
if(Pattern.matches("Y$",text) || Pattern.matches("YEARS$",text) || Pattern.matches("Years",text))
{
//do
}
```

However this is getting failed.

Can someone point me where I have gone wrong or suggest me any other feasible method.

EDIT:

Thanks.That helps.

Finally I have used `"(?i)^.*Y(ears)?$| (?i)^.*M(onths)?$".`

But I want to make more changes to make it perfect.

Let's say I have many strings.

Ideally only strings like 1.5Y or 0.5-3.5Y or 2.5/2.5-4.5Y should pass if check.

```
It can be number of years(Ex:2.5y) or the period of years(2.5-3.5y) or the no of years/period of years(Ex.2.5/3.5-4.5Y) nothing more.

More Examples:
--------------
Y -should fail;
MY - should fail;
1.5CY - should fail;
1.5Y-2.5Y should fail;
1.5-2.5Y should pass;
1.5Y/2.5-3.5Y should fail;
1.5/2.5-3.5Y should pass;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`matches` method attempts to match full input so use:

```
^.*Y$
```

for your first pattern.

btw you can use a single regex for all 3 cases:

```
if (text.matches( "(?i)^.*Y(ears)?$" ) ) {...}
```

`(?i)` does ignore case match.

Answer (score 5):

You don't need a regex here:

```
if(text.endsWith("Y") || ...)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
.*(?:Y|YEARS|Years)$
```

You can directly use this .Match matches from beginning.So yours is failing.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use the regex pattern:

```
if (Pattern.matches(".*(Y|YEARS|Years)$",text)) {/*do something*/}
```

Answer (score 1):

/((?!0)\d+|0)(.\d+)?(?:years|year|y)/gi

https://regex101.com/r/gJ6xD2/2

```
var text = "1.6y   1.5years  1year 1.5h";
text.match(/((?!0)\d+|0)(\.\d+)?(?:years|year|y)/gi);
```

Result["1.6y", "1.5years", "1year"]

Answer (score 0):

```
(?=^(0\.\d+|[1-9](?:\d+)?(?:\.\d+)?)(?:(\s+)?[\/-](\s+)?(?:0\.\d+|[1-9](?:\d+)?(?:\.\d+)?))*(?:\s+)?(?:y(?:(ea)?rs|ears?)?|m(?:onths?)?)$).*
```

https://regex101.com/r/kL7rQ1/3

Only thing I wasn't sure "2.3 - 4 / 6.2 y" format is acceptable or not, so I've included it.